# I have a better_sqlite3.node error when i require quick.db

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, quick.db, better-sqlite3

i dont have errors when i install but when i require quick.db in my main.js (its a discord.js bot in v12)

```js
const db = require('quick.db')
```

i have an ***better_sqlite3.node*** error in my terminal

```
-C:\Users\Fatsah\Desktop\Wizzy Bot\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:121
        throw e;
        ^

Error: The module '\\?\C:\Users\Fatsah\Desktop\Wizzy Bot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\Release\better_sqlite3.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 83. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at bindings (C:\Users\Fatsah\Desktop\Wizzy Bot\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:112:48)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Fatsah\Desktop\Wizzy Bot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\lib\database.js:9:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
PS C:\Users\Fatsah\Desktop\Wizzy Bot>
```

i tried to reinstall and update node.js into the last test

> Node version : v16.7.0

> Discord.js : v12.5.3

> Npm Version : 7.20.3

I have this error not long ago, when I was using `node v14` and I have the same with canvas / canvacord but is `canvas.node`

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall all your dependencies, you probably upgraded Node after you installed `better-sqlite3` and you need to rebuild the library again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by [installing `better-sqlite3` in `Dockerfile` instead of `package.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78161136/6141587) & using `pnpm`'s `supportedArchitectures` feature.